# Procedimientos almacenandos en Laravel no devuelve mas de una tabla

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, rutas

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado en mysql que devuelve 3 tablas, pero al momento de invocarlo con laravel solo me muestra el contenido de la primera tabla.

```html
route::get('/prueba/{id}','Emergencia\AsistenciaMedicaController@prueba');
```

> 

```html
 public  function  prueba($id) {
>        dd ($this->EmergenciaProcedure->prueba()) ;
>         //dd($datos);
>        //dd( DB::select('exec prueba '));
>     }
> 
>  public function prueba() {
>         return \DB::select('call prueba');
>     }
```

Dejo la ruta, la función , el metodo para llamar al sp

[image: Lo que muestra el navegador][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la imagen 1 es el sp en mysql, la segunda como se muestra el contenido en el navegador

Answer (score 0):

Intenta lanzar la consulta con cursores para que eloquent no te parsee la respuesta

```
$db = DB::connection()->getPdo();

$sql = "EXEC prueba"; // Aqui poner los que quieras

$cursor = $db->prepare($sql);
$cursor->execute();

while $dato= $cursor->fetch()) {
    echo $dato . "<br>";
}
```